# ERROR CS0104 Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Hi i'm facing error CS0104 on Xamarin. 
I know it's a common error but as a new developper on C# I don't understand the logic behind.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Standard.models;


namespace Standard
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string json = @"{'id': 4, 'name': 'premier json'}";

        Element element = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Element>(json);

        Console.WriteLine(element.name);

    }
}
```

}

With this simple code I got an error at this line :

```
> Element element = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Element>(json);
```

he underline me Element object.

the error:

> CS0104 'Element' is an ambiguous reference between **Standard.models.Element** and **Xamarin.Forms**

I can avoid the error by doing that:

```
Standard.models.Element element = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Standard.models.Element>(json);
```

But it's stupid if I Have to always indicate where is my object. It make my "using" useless.

Comment: Element is a visual element from Xamarin.Forms, you happen to call your models the same, hence you are forced to specify which Element you mean. Consider calling your element something else, maybe something more descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either rename your `Element` class to something else that does not conflict with `Xamarin.Forms.Element`, or define a specific `using` to qualify it, i.e.

```
using Element = Standard.models.Element;
```

Comment: yeah it work, so it was a conflict with Xamarin.Forms.Elment class.